# HTML JS JQ How to Drag & Drop the content from 2 Textfiles

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

Problem: I´ve got 2 Textfiles with different content, f. E. textfile1 contains "lorem" the textfile2 contains "ipsum". Booth saved in same folder. HOW can i display the 2 files on screen and drag the specific file on screen (into a div or whatever), the other above or under the first file?

i found https://www.html5rocks.com/de/tutorials/dnd/basics/ and the basic from selfhtml and other tutorials but cant get managed to specify the folder.

heres the code, same as tutorial:

```
<div id="dropzone"> Ziehen Sie Ihre Dateien mit Drag & Drop hier herein:
        <br> (Durch Drücken der [strg]-Taste können Sie mehrfach auswählen!) </div>
    <output
    id="list"></output>
</main>
<script>
    function dateiauswahl(evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        evt.preventDefault();
        var gewaehlteDateien = evt.dataTransfer.files; // FileList Objekt
        var output = [];
        for (var i = 0, f; f = gewaehlteDateien[i]; i++) {
            output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a',
                ') - ', f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ', f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString(),
                '</li>');
        }
        document.getElementById('list')
            .innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
    }

    function handleDragOver(evt) {
            evt.stopPropagation();
            evt.preventDefault();
            evt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
        }
        // Initialisiere Drag&Drop EventListener
    var dropZone = document.getElementById('dropzone');
    dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
    dropZone.addEventListener('drop', dateiauswahl, false);

</script>
```

Anyone got an idea of another tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I am doing it. (The code allows you to drag and drop as many .txt files as you need)

I hope that I have correctly understood your question.

```js
var dropzone = document.querySelector('#dropzone');
dropzone.addEventListener("dragenter", onDragEnter, false);
dropzone.addEventListener('dragover', onDragOver, false);
dropzone.addEventListener('drop',onDrop, false);


function onDragEnter(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
}
function onDragOver(evt) {
  evt.stopPropagation();
  evt.preventDefault();
  evt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy'; // it's a copy!
}
function onDrop(evt) {
  evt.stopPropagation();
  evt.preventDefault();

  var files = evt.dataTransfer.files;// object FileList
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
   if(files[i].type == "text/plain"){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
      dropzone.value += event.target.result; 
      //console.log(event.target)
    }
    //instanceOfFileReader.readAsText(blob[, encoding]);
    reader.readAsText(files[i], "UTF-8");
  }else{console.log(files[i].type);}
  }  
}
```

```css
#dropzone {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px dashed;
}
p{text-align:center; margin:2.5em;}
```

```html
<p>Drop one or more .txt files on the textarea:</p>
<textarea id="dropzone"> </textarea>
```

Please read: [Using files from web applications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your Code solves Step2, so thank you anyway :D In this Case i want to save the file in an directory. The display itself works with the tutorial. After the display i want to change the order, i. E. firstfile = lorem, second = ipsum --> fistfile = ipsum, second = lorem.

Comment: I don't understand. If you drag the .txt files in the dropzone, the content of those files is displayed on the screen. Please explain "Step1"

Comment: In this case you drag your files one by one in the order you want them. Or you order your files in the folder in the order you want them, then you select them and drag into the dropzone. Alternatively you may reorder first the `files` object in the order you need.